# How to handle boolean response from web service in android

Tags: android, xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">true</boolean>
```

I am trying to handle this xml response from my web service in my application. How do I use the boolean value to do a certain action in my application?

Comment: Please be more precise, add code (e.g. what you tried) and what exact point you're stuck at.